# How can I create a bootable flash drive for Lbuntu and also store temporarily other personal files in the same flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, parted, flash-memory

I have a flash drive, whose information given by `sudo fdisk -l` is

```
Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 7864319 7864319  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I would like to know how I can use the flash drive for two things simultaneously:

1. a bootable flash drive for Lubuntu 18.04, which is 1GB
2. for storing temporary personal files.

Originally I created a bootable flash drive for Lubuntu 18.04, by

```
dd /path/to/ubuntu.iso /dev/sdb
```

After installing Lubuntu to my laptop,  I didn't know how I could continue to use the flash drive as temporary storage of other personal files, so I asked [how to revert the flash drive back to a storage device for my other personal files only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443604/how-can-i-change-a-flash-drive-back-after-making-it-a-bootable-device-for-ubuntu), and followed the reply there to change my flash drive to be what I have shown at the beginning of this post.

Now I think that in case that my Lubuntu can't boot for whatever reason, I still need to run the OS on a bootable flash drive to retrieve the files on the file systems on my laptop. So here I am asking how I can create a bootable flash drive for Lbuntu and also store temporarily other personal files in the same flash drive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Persistent live drive

**You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to make a persistent live drive with Lubuntu.**

- Very portable between computers
- Personal files can be saved
- Application programs can be installed (but new kernels and hardware drivers cannot be used)
- Sensitive to corruption, so you need frequent backups.

### Installed system

You can also create an [installed linux operating system in a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312), but this 4GB pendrive is too small for that purpose. In order for an installed system to work well, you should have a fast USB3 pendrive with at least 16 GB.

- Portable between computers, but not as portable as a [persistent] live system.
- Flexible, can be made up to date, 'all' program packages, kernels and drivers can be installed. But if you install a proprietary driver for graphics or wifi, the portability may be reduced.
- Very stable except that Windows may hijack the boot system in UEFI mode. This can happen, when you boot Windows with this drive connected, and Windows does a major upgrade.

### Background information

- **Cloning: dd** is a very powerful but also very dangerous tool, often nicknamed 'disk destroyer' or 'data destroyer'. dd is used to **clone** an iso file to a USB pendrive. When creating live-only USB boot drives, **mkusb** 'wraps a safety belt around dd'. This method works for all hybrid iso files, and most modern linux distros provide this kind of iso files. The new **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** in 16.04 LTS uses the cloning method too.
- Many other tools **extract** the content of the iso file to a FAT32 partition, for example **Rufus** and **Unetbootin**. (Rufus has also a cloning  `dd` mode.)
- **mkusb is a linux tool**. It does not work in Windows.
- **mkusb is a bash script**, that uses several standard tools, available in most linux distros. mkusb uses **zenity** for a graphical user interface when available.
- **mkusb-nox** (No X) works in **text mode**, for example in Ubuntu Server. **mkusb-dus** (alias mkusb version 12) can work in text mode too with **dialog** text mode menus or with a plain text interface.
- Some of the other tools consist of **compiled code**.
- mkusb can also work as an extracting tool and create **persistent live systems for Debian and Ubuntu**. These systems are booted via grub2, and the iso file is cloned to a separate partition. A **casper-rw partition** will be created for persistence and a **usbdata partition** will be created for storing data and sharing data with computers running Windows. These persistent live systems can boot in UEFI and BIOS mode.
- mkusb-nox and mkusb-dus (alias version 12) can create a **USB installer for Windows 7-10** via extraction. It uses the grub-pc package to install grub2, which makes the USB pendrive boot in BIOS mode. This system can boot in UEFI and BIOS mode.
- mkusb does *not* create multi-boot USB drives. There are other tools for that purpose.
- mkusb can also **wipe confusing data** and/or **restore a USB boot drive to a standard storage device** with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system.

### Links

- [mkUSB-quick-start-manual](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)
- [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)